# When configuring rsyslog to log to mysql DB, what is purpose of SystemEventsProperties table?

Tags: mysql, syslog, rsyslog

I've configured rsyslog on my servers to log to a remote mysql DB.  I did this essentially by following the [rsyslog wiki](http://wiki.rsyslog.com/index.php/HOWTO_:_Rsyslog_%2B_MySQL_on_FreeBSD) and it essentially creates two tables:

```
mysql> show tables;
+------------------------+
| Tables_in_Syslog       |
+------------------------+
| SystemEvents           |
| SystemEventsProperties |
+------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The first table, `SystemEvents` is pretty straight forward.  That's where my servers logs end up, and I have it working fine -- my logs show up in the DB just fine.  Nothing, however, gets inserted into the SystemEventsProperties table (or nothing thus far), and so I'm trying to figure out what that table is for, and if I can somehow utilize it to my advantage.  If it helps, here's what `describe SystemEventsProperties;` shows:

```
mysql> describe SystemEventsProperties;
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| ID            | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| SystemEventID | int(11)          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| ParamName     | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| ParamValue    | text             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```